# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable in my line of code

Tags: python

i am trying to make a bubble sorting mechanism, but when ium tryinbg to make the part where i want to swap two characters inside of the variable i get the error, and thats why i need help

```
number = '562374'
for x in range(0,7,1):
    y = x+1
    if(number[x] > number[y]) :
        number = int(number)
        number[x], number[y]= number[y],number[x]
        number = str(number)
    print(number)
```

i expect the outcome to be 526374 / 623674 / 623647

but i get the error saying TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable in line 6

Comment: `number` is an `int` when you do `number[x], number[y]= number[y],number[x]`. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: btw, `range(0,7,1)` is the same as `range(7)`

Comment: there's no need to cast your number (which is initially a string) to int, and then cast it back to str. Just work with the string input.

Comment: @Barmar: Although `getal` is otherwise unused; I suspect `getal` and `number` may be the same thing, with only a partial rename for posting.

Comment: about getal: getal is number but in dutch (i wanted to rename it for the post and forgot about them hehe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use subscripts with numbers. You also can't assign to subscripts of strings, because Python strings are immutable.

What you need to do is convert the string to a list at the beginning. Then you can swap the list elements and join them back at the end.

```
number = '562374'
digits = list(number)
for x in range(len(digits)-1):
    y = x+1
    if(digits[x] > digits[y]) :
        digits[x], digits[y] = digits[y], digits[x]
        number = "".join(digits)
    print(number)
```

Comment: Further, if you only wanted to output if the number has actually changed, which seems to be the case based on your example output, you would move the `print` statement inside the `if` statement.